# Let $A\in M_n(\Bbb R)$ be such that the sum of the two largest numbers in each row is $a$, and in each column is $b$. How can I prove that $a=b$?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> In every cell of a square table there is a real number. The sum of the largest two numbers in each row is $a$ and the sum of the largest two numbers in each column is $b$. Prove that $a = b$.

Help! I don't know how to start the problem. I've considered the largest and smallest numbers of such a set, however, I don't know what good using the extremes will bring.

Comment: What contest does this come from?

Comment: @JJM I have a solution, but I don't know of a way to give a reasonable hint. Can you show some work of what you've done by considering the largest number of a row/column?

Comment: Does this generalize to more than two largest numbers?

Comment: @darijgrinberg It's not true for the 3 largest numbers, in a $4\times 4$ grid. We can construct a counter example where the columns are $ 7 = 3 + 2 + 2 (+0) $ and the rows are $ 6 = 3 + 3 + 0 (+0) = 2 + 2 + 2 (+2)$, where the value in parenthesis is the 4th cell of that row/column. This generalizes to show it's not true for the $k \geq 3 $ largest numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each row $i$, let $x_i = x_{i,j(i)}$ be the largest element and $x'_i = x_{i, j'(i)}$ be the second largest element, breaking ties arbitrarily if necessary.

**Hint:**  Show that $ b \geq a$.

**Proof:**  WLOG, $x_1$ is the smallest of the $x_i$.

**Case 1:** There is a column with 2 of these elements $x_i$, say $x_k$ and $x_l$:

> then $b \geq x_k + x_l \geq x_1 + x_1 \geq a  $.

**Case 2:** If not, then each $x_i$ is in it's own column.

> Consider $ x'_1 = x_{i, j'(1)}$.
>  Consider column $j'(1)$, which has corresponding circled number $x_{j'(1)} $.
>  Then,  $b \geq x_{j'(1)} + x'_1 \geq x_1 + x'_1 = a $

**Corollary:** By symmetry, $ a \geq b$ hence $ a = b$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Suppose that $a>b$. Let $d=\frac14(a+b)$, and subtract $d$ from each cell of the table. On the one hand $d<\frac{a}2$, so the sum of the largest two elements in each row is positive, but on the other hand $d>\frac{b}2$, so the sum of the largest two elements in each column is negative.

**Added:** I initially thought that it was almost done at this point, but as Calvin Lin pointed out, we cannot conclude that every column consists entirely of negative numbers and get an immediate contradiction. However, we can immediately conclude that each row contains at least one positive number, and each column contains at most one positive number. This implies that there is exactly one positive number in each row and column.

Now let $x$ be the largest negative number in the table (i.e., the one with the smallest absolute value); say that $x$ is in column $c$. Let $y$ be the positive number in column $c$, say in row $r$. Finally, let $z$ be the largest negative number in row $r$. Then $z<x$, so $0<z+y<x+y<0$, which is absurd. Thus, $a\le b$, and by symmetry $b\le a$, so $a=b$.

Comment: WOW! what is the motivation for this solution?

Comment: @JJM: I’m honestly not sure; I just had the thought that shifting the numbers might make life easier and tried a few things. And I realize now that I could simplify it a bit by subtracting $\frac{a}2$ from each cell: the sum of the largest two elements in each row will then be $0$, but the sum of the largest two elements in each column will be negative, and we run into essentially the same problem.

Comment: @JJM: You’re welcome!

Comment: i am having trouble understanding how exactly does this observation finish? do we reach a contradiction? thank you.

Comment: @JJM: If the sum of the largest two elements in each column is negative, can there be any positive numbers in the table?

Comment: OH wow that is a real beautiful solution :) I get it now, thanks so much for your time.

Comment: @JJM: I have to admit that I was a little surprised myself by how neatly it fell out!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The 2 largest numbers in a column could be $1, -2$ to give a negative sum, so I don't think you're quite done as yet.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get what you're saying. Can you elaborate? What is the contradiction that you're going for?

Comment: @CalvinLin: No, you’re right. I did overlook that possibility. (If you saw the comment a few minutes ago that was up *very* briefly before I deleted it, ignore it: I misread *your* comment.)

Comment: What you've shown is that in each column, there is exactly 1 number that is positive. I can't quite completely push through your approach (without much more details), but it inspired/informed mine (IE Case 2).